# Table usage in the webpage in asp.net(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

```
  int numcells = 2;


          foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileQuery)
          {
              Label1.Text = fileList.Count().ToString();


                  TableRow r = new TableRow();
                  for (int i = 0; i < numcells; i++)
                  {
                      if (i.Equals("0"))
                      {


                          TableCell c = new TableCell();
                          c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(fi.Name.ToString()));
                          r.Cells.Add(c);


                      }
                      if (i.Equals("1"))
                      {


                          TableCell c = new TableCell();
                          c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(Server.MapPath(strheadlinesid).ToString() + fi.Name.ToString()));
                          r.Cells.Add(c);
                      }
                      Table1.Rows.Add(r);

              }
```

I tried with the above code to print file name and and its path in the table.
But for some reason it's not printing the table.
Is there any wrong in the syntax.
       Please let me know the wrong in the code  if anyone finds it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i.Equals("0")` and `i.Equals("1")` is incorrect and should be `i.Equals(0)` and `i.Equals(1)`

This will sort out your problem, Equals is used to determine if the specified object is equal to the current object, and in this case it is not because "1" is a string and 1 is an integer.

have a look `here` for more info on equals

Comment: Haha, no worries, debug is your friend :-)